# Using ! to assign output of shell command to variable in .ipynb

Tags: python, bash, jupyter-notebook, interop

Is there a way to get this on one line:

```bash
> ipython
Python 3.11.1 (main, Jan 24 2023, 17:02:06) [Clang 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202)]
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 8.8.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: l = ! ls

In [2]: l[:3]
Out[2]: ['___x.ipynb', 'data', 'e.txt']

In [3]: l = (! ls)[:3]
  Cell In[3], line 1
    l = (! ls)[:3]
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

?

Ref: https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/01.05-ipython-and-shell-commands.html

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a direct way to do that. You can leverage shell's `head` command for this. Example: `ls | head -n 3` and IPython `l = !ls | head -n 3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to exist a direct way to achieve that in one line under IPython.

According to that [blog post](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/01.05-ipython-and-shell-commands.html):

> anything appearing after `!` on a line will be executed not by the Python kernel, but by the system command-line

and, IPython's [System shell access](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/interactive/reference.html#system-shell-access):

> Any input line beginning with a `!` character is passed verbatim (minus the `!`, of course) to the underlying operating system.

Except for the variables in curly braces that are expanded before the command is passed to the underlying OS shell.

---

One possible solution could be to leverage the shell `head` command for this:

```bash
ls | head -n 3
```

and, in IPython:

```bash
files = !ls | head -n 3
```

---

Another alternative could be to resort to Python solutions such as [`os.listdir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir):

```py
import os
files = [e for e in os.listdir() if not e.startswith('.') and os.path.isfile(e) ][:3]
```

or, [`glob.glob()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob):

```py
import glob
files = glob.glob('*')[:3]
```

Answer (score 1):

I came to the same conclusion as Azeem, that there is no direct way to do this since iPython only seems to support direct assignment of shell output with `=`. `l = !ls | head -n 3` is the probably the best and most readable way to do this in one line in iPython, but here's a Python alternative that will work anywhere:

```
import subprocess
l = subprocess.run(['ls'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.decode('utf-8').splitlines()[:3]
```